# Alguien tiene error con la libreria mike escpos

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, web

Tengo este error al momento de madar los ticket estoy usando la  XPrinter-58IIH como impresora

El mensaje de error es:

> Warning: copy(\JuanNaal\POS-58-Series): Failed to open stream: No
> such file or directory in
> C:\wamp64\www\pos\vendor\mike42\escpos-php\src\Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector.php
> on line 372

mi codigo esta aqui:

```
public function impresionDirecta($idVenta)
{
    $empresa = $this->model->getEmpresa();
    $venta = $this->model->getVenta($idVenta);
    
    $nombre_impresora = "POS-58-Series";
    $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector($nombre_impresora);
    $printer = new Printer($connector);

    # Vamos a alinear al centro lo próximo que imprimamos
    $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);

    /*
        Intentaremos cargar e imprimir
        el logo
    */
    try {
        $logo = EscposImage::load("assets/images/logos/logo.png", false);
        $printer->bitImage($logo);
    } catch (Exception $e) {/*No hacemos nada si hay error*/
    }

    /*
        Ahora vamos a imprimir un encabezado
    */

    $printer->text($empresa['nombre'] . "\n");
    $printer->text('RFC: ' . $empresa['rfc'] . "\n");
    $printer->text('Telefono: ' . $empresa['telefono'] . "\n");
    $printer->text('Dirección: ' . $empresa['direccion'] . "\n");
    #La fecha también
    $printer->text(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "\n\n");

    #Datos del cliente
    $printer->text('Datos del Cliente' . "\n");
    $printer->text('--------------------' . "\n");
    /*Alinear a la izquierda para la cantidad y el nombre*/
    $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
    $printer->text($venta['identidad'] . ': ' . $venta['num_identidad'] . "\n");
    $printer->text('Nombre: ' . $venta['nombre'] . "\n");
    $printer->text('Telefono: ' . $venta['telefono'] . "\n");
    $printer->text('Dirección: ' . $venta['direccion'] . "\n\n");

    $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
    $printer->text('Detalles del Producto' . "\n");
    $printer->text('--------------------' . "\n");
    $productos = json_decode($venta['productos'], true);
    foreach ($productos as $producto) {
        /*Alinear a la izquierda para la cantidad y el nombre*/
        $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
        $printer->text($producto['cantidad'] . "x" . $producto['nombre'] . "\n");

        /*Y a la derecha para el importe*/
        $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_RIGHT);
        $printer->text(MONEDA . number_format($producto['precio'], 2) . "\n");
    }

    /*
        Terminamos de imprimir
        los productos, ahora va el total
    */
    $printer->text("--------\n");
    $printer->text("Abono: " . MONEDA . number_format($venta['abono'], 2) . "\n");
    $printer->text("--------\n");
    $printer->text("TOTAL: " . MONEDA . number_format($venta['total'] - $venta['abono'], 2) . "\n\n");


    /*
        Podemos poner también un pie de página
    */
    $printer->text($empresa['mensaje']);

    /*Alimentamos el papel 3 veces*/
    $printer->feed(3);

    /*
        Cortamos el papel. Si nuestra impresora
        no tiene soporte para ello, no generará
        ningún error
    */
    $printer->cut();

    /*
        Por medio de la impresora mandamos un pulso.
        Esto es útil cuando la tenemos conectada
        por ejemplo a un cajón
    */
    $printer->pulse();

    /*
        Para imprimir realmente, tenemos que "cerrar"
        la conexión con la impresora. Recuerda incluir esto al final de todos los archivos
    */
    $printer->close();
}
```

ya intente cambiando el nombre de la impresora, volviendo a integra la libreria nueva mente alguien sabe si podria ser problema que no sea compatible la impresora

Comment: cuando instalaste la impresora la pusiste para compartir?, a mi me paso lo mismo y en las propiedades de la impresor en la opción compartir habilite la opción y listo.